# html div element with transform rotate(90deg) disappears in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In the following html example the blue box disappears when the chrome window  height is dragged above 1200px. (simplified example)

```html
 <html>    
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        .red_box {
          position: fixed;
          right: calc(-50vh + 1em);
          width: 100vh;
          top: calc(50vh - 1.2em);
          height: 4.9em;
          transform-origin: top;

          transform: rotate(-90deg);
    
          background-color: red;
          will-change: transform;    
        }    
        .blue_box {
          width: 60vh;
          background: blue;
          height: 2em;
    
        }
      </style>
    </head>    
    <body>    
      <div class="red_box">
        <div class="blue_box">
        </div>
      </div>    
    </body>    
    </html>
```

Already filed a bug in the chromium project: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935452

I assume that it is a corner case? And will take some time until this will be fixed. Does anyone know a workaround?

- we need the parent element(red box) to be rotated and near the left or right corner of the window
- Update: in our real application the red_box is always a new layer(browser composite process), so we need the css `will-change: transform;` to force a new layer in the simplified example. The bug seems to be connected with the browser layers.
- Update: We also need a css height around 5em, because we animate the red_box from left to right. The bug does only occur if the html element overlaps the window size.

Comment: Seems to be your ```will-change``` affecting the blue box. If you remove this the blue box stays.

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve our problem, because we need the `will-change` attribute, i updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height` form `.red_box` css.
Please use below code:

```css
        .red_box {
          position: fixed;
          right: calc(-50vh + 1em);
          width: 100vh;
          top: calc(50vh - 1.2em);
          /*height: 4.9em;*/
          transform-origin: top;
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);       
          -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          background-color: red;
          will-change: transform;    
        }    
        .blue_box {
          width: 60vh;
          background: blue;
          height: 2em;        
        }
```

```html
 <html>    
    <head>
    </head>    
    <body>    
      <div class="red_box">
        <div class="blue_box"></div>
      </div>    
    </body>    
  </html>
```

Comment: we need a css height with more than 4em, because we animate the red_box with an simple translationX and need the overlap